# How to use graph data type using by pl/python in AgensGraph?

Tags: plpython, agens-graph

I am using AgensGraph. 
I know the PostgreSQL supports pl/python driver. 
So I think the AgensGraph supports it, too. 
If I want to use a graph data type using by pl/python, is the way same with general data?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use PL/Python in AgensGraph you need to **Create the plpythonu language**.

A good example for PL/Python in AgensGraph would be as following:

**Enabling the module**

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

**Creating sample data**

```
CREATE (a:person {id:1,name:'Bob'});
```

**Creating PL/Python function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION firstname()
RETURNS void
AS $$
#Python source code starts
records = plpy.execute("MATCH (a:person) RETURN a.name AS sample")
plpy.info(records[0]['sample'])
#Python source code ends
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

**Calling the function**

```
SELECT firstname();
```

You can find more information in the following link:
[AgensGraph](https://bitnine.net/documentations/manual/agens_graph_developer_manual_en.html)